# "quickly run" not working anymore

Tags: application-development, quickly

The command `quickly run` is not working after I renamed the folder and created a new one with same name and moved the contents of the renamed folder to the new one .

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: No run command found.
Candidate commands are: commands, getstarted, help, quickly
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `quickly run` command uses a file `.quickly` in the project directory. I think you might have missed this in copying, because it is hidden by default. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see hidden files in the default file manager. Then make sure you move this hidden file to the new directory.

Comment: I get a similar error message: `FEHLER: No tutorial command found.
Candidate commands are: commands, getstarted, help, quickly` also if I use `quickly tutorial ubuntu-application`. Similar message: `FEHLER: No create command found.
Candidate commands are: commands, getstarted, help, quickly` for `quickly create ubuntu-application foobar`

Comment: Can you please expand your question? When the error occured? Have you moved contents to another folder as in the case of op? Have you installed ubuntu-application template

Comment: I wanted to read the tutorial, how is it described in the [Quickly Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly), so I tried the command: `quickly tutorial ubuntu-application`. No, I moved nothing. Is there a package "ubuntu-application template"?

Comment: Yeah, there is an ubuntu-application template package, In normal cases it will be installed with quickly. Any way your question is diffrent, feel free to ask a separate question

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I had to install the package `quickly-ubuntu-template`. `apt-cache show quickly` shows me that the `quickly-ubuntu-template` package only is recommended.