# “quickly tutorial ubuntu-application” not working

Tags: 12.04, application-development, quickly

I installed Quickly with `sudo apt-get install quickly`. If I want to read the tutorial with `quickly tutorial ubuntu-application` I get the following error message:

```
FEHLER: No tutorial command found.
Candidate commands are: commands, getstarted, help, quickly
```

Also if I try `quickly create ubuntu-application foobar`, I get a similar message:

```
FEHLER: No create command found.
Candidate commands are: commands, getstarted, help, quickly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/215704/23878) the package `quickly-ubuntu-template` was missing. If you install the package `quickly` the package `quickly-ubuntu-template` is not installed because it is just recommended. You can see this with `apt-cache show quickly`. So you have to manually install that package.:

```
 sudo apt-get install quickly-ubuntu-template
```